# html, background-image fails to repeat on account of height: 100% setting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage where I have used

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

in order to fill out the rest of the screen when my content doesn’t 
have enough stuff in it to get beyond the bottom.

Because the body/html elements are sized according to the viewport, when I DO
have enough content to scroll, my background image cuts off despite 
what should be a default x/y background repeat behavior.

```
body {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-image: url('../img/stardust3.png');
}
```

The html/body tags keep their 100% height dimensions but a 100% viewport is smaller than a document where you have to scroll. Ultimately, my html/body tags get stuck at the top.

Before this, I was using javascript to grab the document size and constantly change
element dimensions when the screen was resized. Do I have to go back to that?

thanks!

Comment: A fiddle would help - based on your example I put this together: http://jsfiddle.net/8pbtg9r8/1/ - However it is not replicating the problem you are having.

Comment: Also, you are missing a semicolon after 100%

Comment: Yep, missing semi-colon. Wasn't the case in my actual code, but I've updated in case anyone else reads this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only setting `height: 100%` to extend the background-image to the bottom of the page, don't. Backgrounds on the `<html>` element will always fill the viewport regardless of content. Also, there's no built-in margin on the html element. Instead, use:

```
html { background-image: url(../img/stardust3.png); }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: This did the trick. I moved the image from my body css to my html css. I was using height:100% for other reasons, and this fix allowed me to keep that setting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
body{
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

this will make your background not scroll with rest of the page.

```
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

this will make your html,body grow with your content and fill screen if content < 100%.